# maxPadding doesn't work for Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When i use Highstock charts the yAxis legend is difficult to read with the graph lines. Do exists some way to make paddingRight to the lines?

[image: screen shot of the problem]

This is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9ezac/1/

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
    },
    opposite: true,
    maxPadding: .1
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use offset parametr for yAxis.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.offset